# Full text search within N words

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Is it possible to create a tsquery that matches when a word is found up to N words of another word?

For example, with the phrase "**quick** brown fox jumps **over**", I could use the 'followed by' search operator but only if I know exactly how many words are between what I'm looking for:

```
SELECT to_tsquery('simple', 'quick <4> over') @@ to_tsvector('simple', 'quick brown fox jumps over');
```

However I may not know in advance how many words are between what I'm looking for, I'd instead like to do something like:

`to_tsquery('simple', 'quick <?4> over')`

Here I am trying to specify that it could be any of: 1, 2, 3 or 4 words apart. I can't seem to find a way to do this without duplicating the original 'followed by' operator for every variant of a word I need.

Edit: This must scale up to accommodate any larger or more complex valid tsqueries that a user may create. The example provided has been simplified to include only the relevant problem.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
select
    x.*,
    y.*,
    tsquery_phrase(query1, query2, y) as query_text,
    tsquery_phrase(query1, query2, y) @@ to_tsvector('simple', 'quick brown fox jumps over') as result
from
    (   select
            to_tsquery('simple', 'quick') as query1,
            to_tsquery('simple', 'over') as query2) as x
    cross join generate_series(1, 10) as y
where
    tsquery_phrase(query1, query2, y) @@ to_tsvector('simple', 'quick brown fox jumps over')
```

another try:

```
with

sample_data as (
    select
        x.text,
        x.vector,
        q.id as query_id,
        y,
        tsquery_phrase(q.query1, q.query2, y) as query_text,
        tsquery_phrase(q.query1, q.query2, y) @@ x.vector as result
    from
        (   select
                'quick brown fow jumps over but the duck is swimming under' as text,
                to_tsvector('simple', 'quick brown fow jumps over but the duck swimming under'::text) as vector) as x
        cross join (select
                        1 as id,
                        to_tsquery('simple', 'quick'::text) as query1,
                        to_tsquery('simple', 'over'::text) as query2
                    union all
                    select
                        2 as id,
                        to_tsquery('simple', 'duck'::text) as query1,
                        to_tsquery('simple', 'under'::text) as query2) as q
        cross join generate_series(1, 10) as y
    where
        tsquery_phrase(q.query1, q.query2, y) @@ x.vector
        and y = case q.id when 1 then 4 when 2 then 2 end
)

select
    text
from
    sample_data
group by
    1
having
    count(*) = 2
```

Comment: This isn't something I can use as it requires writing custom SQL for each search query, i.e. it couldn't work with: `quick <4> over && duck <2> under`

Comment: not sure if it will help, but added another solution

Comment: This solution isn't viable, having to write SQL for each variant of a search has no use case in the real world. Imagine if Google had to make you wait a day or 2 to develop and implement each of your search queries.

Comment: This code is just an attempt to help you find a viable solution)